# Inserting Data into text file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I inserted data into the text file [text file used in C++ programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRPXH.png)

The data is like this, but it should be in readable form.

Here is the programme

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Record {
    private:
        int id;
        char name[50];
    public:

        void insert_data();
        void show_data();
};

void Record::insert_data() {
    cout << "\n\tName: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name, 50);

    cout << "\n\tID: ";
    cin >> id;
}

void Record::show_data() {
    cout << "\n\tName: ";
    cout << name;
    cout << "\n\tID: ";
    cout << id;
}

void write_info();
void show_info();

int main() {

    //write_info();
    show_info();

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}

void write_info() {
    Record info;
    ofstream data("data.txt", ios::app);
    info.insert_data();
    data.write((char *)(&info), sizeof(Record));
    data.close();
} // Function Ends here

void show_info() {
    Record info;
    ifstream data("data.txt", ios::app);
    data.read((char *)(&info), sizeof(Record));
    info.show_data();
    data.close();
}
```

Why such type of data (which is not readable) been entered into text file?
Please check my programme, if there is an error due to that this unreadable data
is in text file.

Comment: you are writing raw memory into the file. The int will be 4 bytes of unreadable data (since it's not stored as text in memory but as binary twos complement). Then there will be some readable text (depending on the encoding), but if your `name` is not 50 characters long then after the name the rest will be just what's in memory. Since you're compiling in debug mode with visual studio un-initialized memory has a value of `0xCD` which is `Í` when decoded as latin-1

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? If you want a readable format then you need to define the exact format. If you want a number and some text then you need to think about how you would delimit that

Comment: I just want to view the data in the text, the data which i entered via the c++ programme. Also the point you explained in the comment#1 can you give me any source (article,url etc) which describes me that point clearly, cause i'am not getting the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream data("data.txt", ios::app);
```

`ios::app` is the append flag. Don't use it with `ifstream`. Since you are reading binary data then use `ios::binary` flag for both `ofstream` and `ifstream`.

Evidently, you want to save data in text form (wise choice). Use `data >> info.name` and `data >> info.id` to write the data instead.

You can also use `std::string name` instead of `char name[50]`. Use `std::getline` if you want to read the whole line.

```
class Record {
public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
    void Record::insert_data() {
        cout << "Name: ";
        getline(cin, name); //reads the whole line
        cout << "ID: ";
        cin >> id;
    }

    void Record::show_data() {
        cout << "Name: " << name << ", ID: " << id << "\n";
    }
};

void write_info() {
    Record info;
    info.insert_data();
    ofstream data("data.txt", ios::app);
    data << info.name << "\n" << info.id << "\n";
} 

void show_info() {
    Record info;
    ifstream data("data.txt");
    while(true) {
        if(!data.good()) break;
        data >> info.name;
        if(!data.good()) break;
        data >> info.id;
        info.show_data();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, i understood what are you telling me. But please tell me why the data i entered in the file was not in the readable form (however the format of the file was text). I  used file.write((Char *) (&info),sizeof(Record)), why this all is happening i can't understand. Please elaborate me this point. Thankyou so much.

Comment: `(char*)` in the argument of `ofstream::write` is used as "cast". It doesn't convert anything to text. It only asks the compiler to suppress the error warning. A byte is same as "`unsigned char`", that's where `char*` comes in. The bytes at the address `&info` are written byte by byte, this is binary, as opposed to text which converts numbers to ASCII values.